# Error al enviar E-mail desde Java

Tags: java, java-8, mail

He intentado hacer un programa para que envie un E-mail al ejecutar la App, solo quiero eso por ahora, despues hare que si se cumple una condicion se envie a una serie de contactos todos los dias, alimentando esos contactos desde una base de datos, pero no consigo que envie un correo de prueba para ver si funciona, he seguido varios tutoriales pero no me sirven.

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class EmailSenderService {
private final Properties properties = new Properties();

private String password;

private Session session;

private void init() {

    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.gmail.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port",25);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.mail.sender","emisor@gmail.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.user", "usuario");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
}

public void sendEmail(){

    init();
    try{
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress((String)properties.get("mail.smtp.mail.sender")));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("receptor@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Prueba");
        message.setText("Texto");
        Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp");
        t.connect((String)properties.get("mail.smtp.user"), "password");
        t.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        t.close();
    }catch (MessagingException me){
                    //Aqui se deberia o mostrar un mensaje de error o en lugar
                    //de no hacer nada con la excepcion, lanzarla para que el modulo
                    //superior la capture y avise al usuario con un popup, por ejemplo.
        return;
    }

}
```

}

El error que me da es:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
javax/activation/DataHandler
at 
EnvioEmail/Archivos.EmailSenderService.sendEmail(EmailSenderService.java:34)
at EnvioEmail/Archivos.Main.main(Main.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataHandler
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 2 more
```

No entiendo donde esta el error, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes una excepción ClassNotFoundException (Clase no encontrada).

Eso significa que no tienes en tiempo de ejecución el paquete donde se haya la clase `javax.activation.DataHandler`.

Probablemente tu IDE (Eclipse, o Netbeans, por citar dos conocidos) está trabajando en modo *compatible* con Java 8, donde dicha clase es parte de de JavaSE (viene por defecto).

En Java 9 el paquete `javax.activation` fue marcado como *Deprecated* (desaconsejado) porque en las nuevas versiones dicho paquete desaparecería de JavaSE (todo se ha vuelto modular, las clases disponibles por defecto son menos).

En Java 11 dicho paquete ya no está disponible, con lo que necesitas añadirlo como una librería externa. Puedes usar [Jakarta Activation](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaf/)

Comment: No entiendo a que se refiere que no lo tengo en tiempo de ejecución

Comment: Actualizo la respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias lo probare

Comment: Mil gracias compañero me funciono